# Regex add new line before each word

Tags: c#, regex

I want to add a new line (CR) in front of each word, where world is anything between spaces **that contains** letters

For example for input string:

```
+48 123 456 789 fax: +48 987 654 321
```

I would like the end result to be:

```
+48 123 456 789
fax: +48 987 654 321
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tried Regex.Replace(text, @"(\b)", @"\n$1"), but that added CR before each number.

Comment: Or rather not CR, but just "\n" string

Comment: Yes. As long as word contains letters - at least one - between spaces then yeah.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"(.*\s)([a-zA-Z]+)(.*)", @"\1\n\2\3")
```

https://regex101.com/r/Tv86Mf/1

Comment: Thanks! Works just like I need it to (ᵔᴥᵔ)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a code like this:

```
Regex.Replace(txt, @"\s+(\w+:\s+)", "\n$1")
```

[**C# Fiddle Demo**](http://rextester.com/JBGQ20641)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed (ᵔᴥᵔ)